# "Lib" issues when installing apps

Tags: 20.04

First of all, I'm using 20.04 last version (linux kernel 5.4.0-48-generic).
I try to install some apps like Spotify, Discord , Steam ... all of them are gave me these library errors. Why did It happened and how to fix it?

For Spotify:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  spotify-client: Dependencies:      libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
                                     libavcodec57 but it is not installable or
                                     libavcodec-extra57 but it is not installable or
                                     libavcodec-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                                     libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 but it is not installable or
                                     libavcodec54 but it is not installable or
                                     libavcodec-extra-54 but it is not installable
                  Reccomends:        libavformat57 but it is not installable or
                                     libavformat-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                                     libavformat54 but it is not installable
```

For Steam:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      steam: Dependencies:  libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            libtxc-dxtn0 but it is not installable
             Dependencies:  libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed
             Recomends:     mesa-vulkan-drivers but it is not going to be installed
             Recomends:     mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
```

For Discord:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  discord: Dependencies: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
           Dependencies: libappindicator1 but it is not installable
           Dependencies: libc++1 but it is not installable
```

All apps give me similar errors. Even It's unusuable now except browsing the internet.

Please help.

By the way It's a clean install. I just downloaded a couple hours ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: @N0rbert No, It didn't. I followed Instructions step by step, but no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install 3rd party deb files that are for an *older* Ubuntu release (or not for Ubuntu at all) - for example, it appears to depend on `libavcodec57` whereas 20.04 uses `libavcodec58`

Comment: I just replaced Ubuntu to Pop_! OS and It's still same! @steeldriver If even I try to install `libavcodec58`, nope! It doesn't work. "you have held broken packages" for downloading them so not single one of them doesn't install. When I try to uninstall It, It even wants to delete desktop and 3gigs of things (entire os I think).